# Xamarin iOS - XAML IsVisible binding does not update when ItemsSource is changed

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I have a binding in XAML which is linked to an list of objects as the ItemsSource. On Android when I update the ItemsSource it updates the binding in the XAML succesfully.

However on iOS this does not work for some reason. Can anyone suggest why ?

Initial declaration of the ItemsSource :

```
users.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<AccountGroup>(Accounts);
```

CS Code which updates the ItemsSource :

```
            users.ItemsSource = null;
            users.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<AccountGroup>(Accounts);
```

This is the Account Group object :

```
public class Account : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string student_unique_id { get; set; }

        public string student_fullname { get; set; }

        public string organisation_id { get; set; }

        public string organisation_title { get; set; }

        public string student_token { get;set;}

        public string reg_branding_url { get;set;}

        public string tint_colour { get;set;}

        public string font_colour { get;set;}

        public string topup_product_id { get;set;}

        public bool isVisible { get; set; }

        public string student_initial 
        { 
            get
            {
                return student_fullname[0].ToString();
            } 
        }

        public string school_image
        {
            get
            {
                return $"{Constants.apiBaseUrl}store/images/uploaded/mobile/{reg_branding_url}";
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public class AccountGroup : List<Account>, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string organisation_title { get; set; }
        public string school_image { get; set; }
        public string tint_colour { get; set; }

        public string font_colour { get; set; }

        public AccountGroup(string orgTitle, string orgImage, string orgTint, string orgFont, List<Account> accounts) : base(accounts)
        {
            organisation_title = orgTitle;
            school_image = orgImage;
            tint_colour = orgTint;
            font_colour = orgFont;
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

And this is the XAML with the IsVisible property :

```
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout>
                <Frame IsVisible="{Binding isVisible}" IsEnabled="False" HasShadow="True" BackgroundColor="White" Padding="0">
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                        <behaviors:Expander x:Name="MainExpander" CollapseAnimationLength="500" IsExpanded="False" IsVisible="True" >
```

Can anyone suggest how to fix this ? Seems strange it works on Android and not iOS. Thanks !

Comment: is it only IsVisible that is not updated?  Do other properties update?  Have you tried forcing the update on MainThread?

Comment: You are implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` but you are never calling `OnPropertyChanged`. It is weird that it works on Android. Also it is not a good practise to set the ItemSource to Null and set a New one

Comment: Jason - none of the properties seem to update. I’ve tried on the main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From document [From Data Bindings to MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm),we know that:

> ViewModels generally implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface,
> which means that the class fires a PropertyChanged event whenever one
> of its properties changes. The data binding mechanism in Xamarin.Forms
> attaches a handler to this PropertyChanged event so it can be notified
> when a property changes and keep the target updated with the new
> value.

In code `Account.cs` , you implemented interface `INotifyPropertyChanged`, but you didn't called `OnPropertyChanged`.So even the value is changed,the UI will not refresh.

You can refer to the following code:

```
 public class Account: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _student_fullname;
    public string student_fullname
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _student_fullname, value); }

        get { return _student_fullname; }
    }

    private bool _isVisible;
    public bool isVisible
    {
        set { SetProperty(ref _isVisible, value); }
        get { return _isVisible; }
    }

// you can modify other codes to trigger `SetProperty` just as above code


    bool SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (Object.Equals(storage, value))
            return false;

        storage = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(propertyName);
        return true;
    }

    protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Note:**

You can modify other fields in class `Account` to trigger `SetProperty` just as above code. The same with class `AccountGroup.cs`

**In addition**,you can define a global variable for your `users.ItemsSource`,for example:

```
   public ObservableCollection<AccountGroup> items { get; private set; }
```

And initialize it as follows:

```
   items = new ObservableCollection<AccountGroup>();
```

Initial declaration of the ItemsSource :

```
 users.ItemsSource = items;
```

In this condition,if you want the collectionview to automatically update as items are added, removed and changed in the underlying list, we'll need to use an `ObservableCollection`.And we don't need the following code:

```
users.ItemsSource = null;
            users.ItemsSource = new System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection<AccountGroup>(Accounts);
```